# Whatever user I login with, details are always the same

Tags: c#, android, sharedpreferences

Edit 1: Basically sharedpreferences aren't being cleared.

In my app, no matter what account I login with, it'll always show the details of the first account that signed up in my database.

E.g. I created an account called "Joe" and filled in the details, every other account that signs in, the details are the same as "Joe" but in the database the details are different.

I'm making this in C# Xamarin with an azure database.

I think it's something to do with sharedpreferences but I can't see the problem as I'm only new to it.

Here's the login and main profile where I most likely made the error:

Login:

```
    static ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
    ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = pref.Edit();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Set our view from the "sign in" layout resource
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Dialog_Sign_In);
        EditText username = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtUsername);
        EditText password = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtPassword);
        username.Text = pref.GetString("UserName", "");
        password.Text = pref.GetString("Password", "");
        var login = FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnDialogSignin);
        login.Click += TryLoginAsync;
    }

    private async void TryLoginAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditText txtUsername = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtUsername);
        EditText txtPassword = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtPassword);
        string user = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
        string zPassword = txtPassword.Text;

        if (!await DBHelper.DoesUserExist(user))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Invalid Login", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            users u = await DBHelper.GetUser(user);
            if (PasswordStorage.VerifyPassword(zPassword, u.password))
            {
                ISharedPreferences pref = GetSharedPreferences("Login", FileCreationMode.Private);
                ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = pref.Edit();
                edit.Clear();
                edit.PutString("Username", u.username);
                edit.PutString("Password", u.password);
                edit.PutString("UserID", u.ID);
                edit.PutString("UserName", u.username);
                edit.PutString("LoggedIn", "true");
                edit.PutString("Password", u.password);
                edit.Commit();
                Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "Success", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                if (await DBHelper.IsUserProfileCreated(u.ID))
                {
                    //go to main menu
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Logged In and user made", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    StartActivity(typeof(SetUpProfile));
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Welcome to your Profile", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    StartActivity(typeof(MainProfile));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Invalid Login", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

MainProfile:

```
    public static MobileServiceClient Client =
    new MobileServiceClient("https://appname.azurewebsites.net");

    protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main_Profile);
        ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);

        String maUsername = pref.GetString("Username", null);
        String maPassword = pref.GetString("Password", null);
        var logout = FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnLogout);

        CurrentPlatform.Init();
        List<UserProf> ls = await Client.GetTable<UserProf>().ToListAsync();
        UserProf mProf = ls.Where(x => x.Username == maPassword).FirstOrDefault();
        //UserProf prof = await Client.GetTable<UserProf>().Where(u => u.Username == username ).ToListAsync();
        TextView textName = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textName);
        textName.Text = mProf.Firstname;
        TextView textProfession = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textProfession);
        textProfession.Text = mProf.Profession;
        logout.Click += LogoutProcess;
        //Toast.MakeText(this, "Hello " + mProf.Firstname + " or " + username, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }

    private void LogoutProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISharedPreferences prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Login", FileCreationMode.Private);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
        editor.Clear();
        editor.Commit();
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Logged Out", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: sharedpreferences will be Store Permanently and its data inside it will not be changed Unless you have specifically Change it.

So i assume everytime you open you apps you will read the sharedpreference data to load the login details, 

- make sure you clear/destroy your sharepreference whenever you close apps or log out. 
- make sure you change the sharepreference data whenever you login with a new login account.

Comment: another tips for you to debugging is, use Toast to display the sharepreference data, to check if the Data in the Preference store the value that you expecting.

Comment: On my mainprofile page, I have a logout button where I have editor.clear, is that not how you wipe sharedpreferences?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio and Code in Android Java?

Comment: I think what you doing is correct, I develop in Android Java, the Syntax is use is in small case, clear() / commit() instead of Clear() / Commit(). You can also try use Apply() instead of Commit().

Comment: I'm using visual studio C#